# How to activate my javascript function with a paragraph on top of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had a working function in Javascipt. When you clicked on an image, the images would move to a different position and a large version of the image, as well as a paragraph, would show up on top. Then I added text over each image. I think it stopped working because you are technically no longer clicking on an image, but you are clicking on a paragraph. I tried to update the javascript code to reflect this, but had no success. I'm still trying to accomplish the same goal, but while having the text stay over the image as they are animated. Let me know if you think you know how to solve this, or if you need more info. I'm new to programming so any help would be useful. Thank you so much. (you may have to scroll to the right to see some of the images) https://jsfiddle.net/xfk3rh8b/

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6')
 document.getElementById('column7').classList.add('animate7')
 document.getElementById('column8').classList.add('animate8')
 document.getElementById('column9').classList.add('animate9');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}
.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
.column:hover p {
  opacity:1;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.column img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative; 
  top: -7px;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height:400px;
  left:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}


.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head7::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head8::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head9::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:280px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column7 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate7 {
  -webkit-animation: animate7 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate7 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column8 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate8 {
  -webkit-animation: animate8 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate8 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
#column9 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate9 {
  -webkit-animation: animate9 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate9 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
    left:262px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:340px;
    left:252px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 930px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    left:228px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px) and (min-width: 850px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: magenta;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:270px;
    left:210px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:250px;
    left:188px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 735px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:230px;
    left:178px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) and (min-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:210px;
    left:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p id='column1p'>this will be shown on the hover 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>this will be shown on the hover 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column7'>
      <img src="https://opticsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/a-telescope.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> computer </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column8'>
      <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> adap tennis </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column9'>
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head9'> telescope </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 9</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Removed the z-index and added a `pointer-event: none` to the `.column p` in css...

**MDN Documentation on *point events***: *The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.*

```css
.column p {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
var click = 0;
function checkClicks(imgs) {

 if(click == 0) {
    // Run your animation on first click
    document.getElementById('column1').classList.add('animate1')
    document.getElementById('column2').classList.add('animate2')
    document.getElementById('column3').classList.add('animate3')
 document.getElementById('column4').classList.add('animate4')
 document.getElementById('column5').classList.add('animate5')
 document.getElementById('column6').classList.add('animate6')
 document.getElementById('column7').classList.add('animate7')
 document.getElementById('column8').classList.add('animate8')
 document.getElementById('column9').classList.add('animate9');
    // hold Images for 1s
  setTimeout(function(){ 
   myFunction(imgs);
  }, 2000);
 } else {
  myFunction(imgs);
 }

 click = 1;
}
function myFunction(imgs) {

 var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
 expandImg.src = imgs.src;
 var imgParagraph = document.getElementById('img-paragraph');
 imgParagraph.innerHTML = imgs.getAttribute("head");

 expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "table-cell";
   imgParagraph.style.display = 'table-cell';
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}
.column p {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
.column:hover p {
  opacity:1;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */

.column img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition-duration: .6s;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.column img:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  position: relative; 
  top: -7px;
  transition-duration: .6s;
}

#totalbody {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 600px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* The expanding image container */

#expandedImg {
  position: absolute;
  height:400px;
  left:300px;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  top: 320px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-height: 430px;
}


/* Expanding image text */


/* image paragraph */

#img-paragraph {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
  right: 30px;
  top: 120px;
}

#expanded-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Closable button inside the expanded image */

.row {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
}

.head1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head4 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head5 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head6 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}
.head7 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head8 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}

.head9 {
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  top: 16px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
}


.head1::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head2::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head3::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head4::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head5::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head6::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head7::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head8::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.head9::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: -16px;
}
.para1{
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
  left: 6%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#column1 {
  position: absolute;
  width:250px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  top:30px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate1 {
  -webkit-animation: animate1 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate1 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;

  }
}
@keyframes animate1 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
      position: absolute;
      top: 500px;
      left:300px;
  }
}
#column2 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:350px;
  top:50px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate2 {
  -webkit-animation: animate2 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate2 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:50px;
  }
}
#column3 {
  position: absolute;
  width:260px;
  float:left;
  left:400px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate3 {
  -webkit-animation: animate3 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate3 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate3 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:600px;
  }
}
#column4 {
  position: absolute;
  width:280px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate4 {
  -webkit-animation: animate4 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate4 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate4 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px;
    left:100px;
  }
}
#column5 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:300px;
  top:80px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate5 {
  -webkit-animation: animate5 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate5 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate5 {
  0% {
    top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left:900px;
  }
}
#column6 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate6 {
  -webkit-animation: animate6 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate6 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate6 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:500px;
  }
}
#column7 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate7 {
  -webkit-animation: animate7 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate7 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate7 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:1000px;
  }
}
#column8 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate8 {
  -webkit-animation: animate8 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate8 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate8 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:200px;
  }
}
#column9 {
  position: absolute;
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  left:600px;
  font-size:0;
}

.animate9 {
  -webkit-animation: animate9 2s normal ease-out;
  animation: animate9 2s forwards normal ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
@keyframes animate9 {
  0% {
      top:00px;
  }
  100% {
    position:absolute;
    top: 800px;
    left:800px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) and (min-width: 1150px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:350px;
    left:262px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1150px) and (min-width: 1050px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:340px;
    left:252px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1050px) and (min-width: 930px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: brown;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:300px;
    left:228px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 930px) and (min-width: 850px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: magenta;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:270px;
    left:210px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 800px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:250px;
    left:188px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 735px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:230px;
    left:178px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 735px) and (min-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #img-paragraph {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    height: 350px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: right;
    right: 30px;
    top: 145px;
  }
  #expandedImg {
    position: absolute;
    height:210px;
    left:150px;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    top: 320px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-height: 430px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

.column p {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/styleprojects.css" />
    <script src='../Javascript/script.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/fix.js'></script>
    <script src='../Javascript/jquery-3.5.1.min.js'></script>
    <title>Projects</title>
</head>
<body id='totalbody'>

  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
    <a class="link" href="communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div id="expanded-wrapper">
      <img id="expandedImg">
      <p id="img-paragraph"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" id='column1'>
      <img src="../Images/arcade.jpeg" alt="Arcade" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head1'> Parapraph #1 </p><p class='para1'> Lorem ipsum dolor si
        t amet consectetur adipisicing
         elit. Sed natus, recusandae veritatis ipsum quia commodi tenetur laboriosam pariatur nihil incidunt architecto velit so
        luta placeat repellat asperiores iure eos dolorum fugiat?</p>"  onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p id='column1p'>this will be shown on the hover 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column2'>
      <img src="../Images/car.png"
        alt="Car" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head2'> Parapraph #2 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
        <p>this will be shown on the hover 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column3'>
      <img src="../Images/pinball.jpeg" alt="Pinball Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head3'> Parapraph #3 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column4'>
      <img src="../Images/vending.jpeg" alt="Vending Machine" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head4'> Parapraph #4 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column5'>
      <img src="../Images/sriraques.jpeg" alt="Sriracha Quesadillas" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head5'> Parapraph #5 </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 5</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column6'>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTWUVh_Aa4CeLecqvG5L-Xzej1kc1tKwDriiWAVWuUMms5JLHQt&usqp=CAU" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head6'>  web code </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column7'>
      <img src="https://opticsmag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/a-telescope.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head7'> computer </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 7</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column8'>
      <img src="https://nctennis.com/common/controls/image_handler.aspx?thumb_id=13&image_path=/images/2018/11/27/Wheelchair.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head8'> adap tennis </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 8</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column" id='column9'>
      <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/77/170477-050-1C747EE3/Laptop-computer.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" head="<p class='head9'> telescope </p>" onclick="checkClicks(this);">
      <p>this will be shown on the hover 9</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The hover feature with the words over the images doesn't function anymore...

Comment: you should look at the images all the way to the right to make sure the hover feature is still working

Comment: Okay, I think your issue is `pointer-event`... I have updated the answer...